# Segmentation fault - GDB Debugging

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gdb, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I am working in eclipse plugin development project. The product in which I am working has GDB debugging. using our product users debug there c projects.

Recently we migrated our project from 3.x to 4.0. After this migration GDB debugging is not working whatever c project  I am trying to debug it is throwing error segmentation fault.

I am able to debug those projects in our product 3.x version.

Don't know why? Please some one give me idea why this error is coming.

Comment: Chinna, a lot more info will be needed to resolve your issue, like are you generally up to date with GDB. (I assume that the 4.0 is a simplification, Eclipse 4.0 is not a usable release, the current one is 4.5 with 4.6 less than a month away).

Comment: @JonahGraham we are using eclipse 4.4.2 abd CDT version 8.x

Comment: And gdb version? I am sorry you are having issues, but without some more details I can't help. Can you provide the trace for mi? Can you reproduce the failure by interacting with gdb directly? If gdb is segfaulting you are surely hitting a gdb bug, possibly exposed by CDT leveraging functionality it didn't used to in older versions.

Comment: @JonahGraham I think GDB version 7.0 i am saying this by referring the GDB plugin version in eclipse. I don't know how to interact with the GDB directly.Do you know tutorial that will help in GDB Debugging. Please help man.

Comment: GDB is a command line tool. Drop down to your command prompt and type "gdb --version". To debug with gdb at the command line do "gdb name_of_executable" and you are off and running. I am not recommending using GDB without Eclipse CDT all the time, but simply knowing what you are doing with it would be useful.

Comment: @JonahGraham thanks for the reply. My GDB version NU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02 thanks for teaching me how to find GDB version. Now i will try to debug my project as you said in command line.

Comment: @JonahGraham actually why I am keen about eclipse GDB debugging.  Now I am working on product developed using eclipse plugin development. Using that product our users debug their "c/c++" project they don't know anything about command line debugging they will only try use our product for gdb debugging.

Comment: As an Eclipse CDT committer, I am very keen on using it too. But if you are shipping a product to customers based on CDT I think you need to know how CDT and GDB interact a little. i.e. with the goal of understanding why you segfault. My guess is once you collect the information ([MCVE]) you will be able to easily resolve your problem (perhaps with my or other people's help)